# Team system best practices - how to mark changes as belonging to specific subject

Tags: tfs, version-control

When working with tfs (or other source control systems) there are many times when I have changes in source files that are related to different tasks (and may be checked in separately - whenever a specific task is complete).
a similar issue is distinguishing between changes that should be checked in, and temporary changes that should be undone.

Is there method to annotate or mark the changes?

**EDIT**

The Mercurial Queues feature presented by @nicolaskruchten appears to be just what i'm looking for.
Is there a similar feature (or extension) for tfs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about TFS but in Mercurial there is the mq system, which lets you manage sets of changes as a queue of patches which you can work on separately. See here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial

Other than that, in Git or other distributed VCS's (including Mercurial) you would usually just go ahead and make a branch or clone another repo, given how easy and common merging is.